# How to call colors in resources dynamically in Android?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, imageview

I am trying to use colors created in my `res/values/colors.xml` file. But when I make the call dynamically the program doesn't compile and instead recommends: `Should pass resolved color instead of a resource id.`

Color Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="gold">#857500</color>
  <color name="green">#0B3B0B</color>
</resources>
```

Activity Code:

```
title.setTextColor(R.color.green); 
help.setTextColor(R.color.gold);
settings.setTextColor(R.color.gold);
logout.setTextColor(R.color.gold);
profile.setTextColor(R.color.green);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Change the code to the following:

```
title.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green)); 
help.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gold));
settings.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gold));
logout.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gold));
profile.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
```

Comment: above code is deprecated try this 

ContextCompat.getColor(CalenderDetailActivity.this, R.color.green)